# Mysterious spikes in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I am using Mathematica 9 and get these strange spikes when I plot the following simple function. I have seen a previous post about this but cannot figure out what is wrong with the following code. Does anyone know how to get rid of them? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
f[q_, L_] := If[q < 1/(1 + L^0.5), 10*q]

Plot3D[f[q, L], {q, 0, 1}, {L, 0, 5}, BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {"q", "L", "Price"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.6], Blue]]
```

[image: spikes]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why it looks like that.  However:

It looks like you are trying to restrict the plot region and you do this by defining the function to return `Null` in other areas.  This is not the usual way to do it.

Use `RegionFunction` instead.

```
Plot3D[10*q, {q, 0, 1}, {L, 0, 5}, BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {"q", "L", "Price"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.6], Blue], 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{q, L}, q < 1/(1 + L^0.5)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]